# Visual Studio reports (RDLC) - multiple tables in one report?

Tags: visual-studio, report, rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation

I'm working with Visual Studio Reports (`rdlc` files) for the first time, so I'm still quite new to it, and I don't know if this can actually be done.

I want to have a report that contains multiple tables of the same "type" (i.e.: with the same columns).

Now, obviously I can do this "by hand" by adding multiple tables to the designer. But here's the catch: **I don't know beforehand how many tables I have to display**!

So basically what I'd want is some sort of "repeater", a way to put "a list of tables" on the report, and then pass an array of data sources in code that would be used to populate them.

Can this be done at all? I don't see anything obvious in the designer that would allow me to achieve this... is it possible?

If not, could this maybe be done with a more advanced solution, like Crystal Reports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your tables have the same columns - use single table with the grouping by whatever criteria that defines "how many" tables you need to have. It would appear as if you have multiple tables on the resulting report. You can display report header for each group and if needed start each on new page.

Bottom line, don't think about it as multiple tables, it's the same table with the data driving how it is being displayed on the report.

Maybe helpful:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251700(v=vs.90).aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/767067/RDLC-Report-Grouping-with-Page-Break-Table-Header

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks. Only thing I had to do was merging all my tables into a single one